# Storing input from HTML from in JS object

Tags: javascript, html, object, input

I am beginner in JS and trying to figure out how do objects work. Currently, I'm stuck with storing information inside them. My goal is to collect user input from forms and to add the directly to the object, bind event listener to a button that would add the input and console log it for test to see if it stored.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form>
        <input placeholder="Name" id="name" type="text"></br>
        <input placeholder="Surname" id="sName" type="text"></br>
        <input placeholder="Age" id="age" type="number"></br>
        <button id="btn" type="button">Submit</button> 
    </form>
```

And my JS looks like this:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

const newUser = {
    name: "replace me with new data",
    surname: "replace me with new data", 
    age: "replace me with new data",
};

function updateUser() {
    newUser.name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    newUser.surname = document.getElementById('sName').value;
    newUser.age =  document.getElementById('age').value;
}

btn.addEventListener('click',updateUser());
```

I have tried to do it like this, but it didn't work:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

const newUser = {
    name: document.getElementById('name').value,
    surname: document.getElementById('sName').value, 
    age: document.getElementById('age').value,
    showInput: function() {
        console.log(newUser);    
    }
};

btn.addEventListener('click',newUser.showInput());
```

I know it could be a very dumb question, but it's my first one on this website and I hope that it won't be the last one. Thank you for spending your time on answering it!

P.S. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: You should not invoke the callback functions on page load. `updateUser()` should be `updateUser` and `newUser.showInput()` should be `newUser.showInput`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!